# Is there anyone who has used OneSignal sendtag in PhoneGap build?

Tags: javascript, tags, phonegap-build, onesignal

Here is what I have done to send tags
-1 add the following function:

```
OneSignal.sendTag("tag", "tagValue").then(function(tagsSent){
   alert(" tag :" + JSON.stringify(tagsSent)) ;
```

})

-2 add the file OneSignalSDK.js in local, because the cdn did not work, had error message

The problem seem that the tag is never sent and there is no error message..
Any idea ?

Comment: Please edit the currently irrelevant title, it should describe the core of your problem rather than be a survey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have the answer, thanks to ONeSignal support team:
I just had to call

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTag("entreprise", "amcreatives");
```

into the OnDeviceReady function.
That's all